# Blender 2.8 Texture Painting weird brush behaivior

Tags: texture-painting

I finished modelling my mesh and wanted to start texture painting it. However there is an issue i cant figure out. I want to draw solid lines, but the lines i draw are kinda noisy, like its from a spray can.
[image]
However, when i draw in the image editor instead of directly to the mesh, the lines are solid and it works.
[image]
I want to draw directly to the mesh and still want the line to be solid.

I opened a new fresh blender project and started texture painting and it worked there. Compared the painting settings, but couldnt find any differences. I do not use a texture as brush, already checked that.

Edit:
Found out, that when i turn off Symmetrie the lines are solid again.
[image]

Comment: Please turn the edit to an answer, so people will find it easily if they have the same issue.

Comment: @FFeller im not sure if its really a solution, because i want to texture paint with symmetrie. Without mirror i have to draw both sides exactly the same. Added the edit for further information.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this issue. While playing around with some settings i figured out that this is only when i activate symmetrie. However if i turn of the symmetrie, the lines are solid again.
[image]

Now the workaround is to draw like that with symmetrie on, so you have your drawing applied and its mirrored even with the weird brush and then you turn off symmetrie, increase the radius of the brush a little bit and draw on top of the weird lines. Its a bit extra work, but the best solution i found so far.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a bowl I was making.

I merged vertices by distance and it turned out I had hundreds of instances of two or more vertices in the same spot. Must have duplicated them accidentally. Merging fixed the issue.